# Sendgrid - account whitelisted and was suspended because of unexpected request behavior

Tags: sendgrid, account, whitelist, mailing

Need Help, our account was logged out when one of my team member accidentally add an IP in whitelisted / allow-listed IP in IP Access Management. Already submit a ticket for the issue, but now they reply me with ***"Your account was suspended"***.

That shocked the production team, since this is a busy week for us.

Is there any way to solve these 2 matters in here, like we need immediate answers for our issues. If it's need to be place a call on us for the issue, please do.

This is our tickets number: *#8595285* and *#8588776* (merged into 8595285).

Here is the people who respond on our ticket:

- Mihai Petrovici |Tech Support Engineer
- Ruxandra Andrioae |Technical Support Engineer Twilio-Sendgrid

Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not the Sendgrid support channel.

Comment: Interesting, because this is came from a section in support.sendgrid.com that I have clicked, is there a sendgrid channel in the stack?

Comment: @MuhamadDimasKennyWirawan, well they shouldn't do that. But it doesn't change the fact that this isn't SendGrid support. Please see [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577)

Comment: @Chris, Righto. Thanks for the reply, I thought Stack can also be a place to ask customer service-related questions.

Answer (score 0):

Today Sendgrid is misbehaving I had a similar issue creating a new account. The site keeps loading forever then a screen comes up telling me I need to contact support. Because you're going through the same thing I guess we try resolve it through customer support first before we go crazy

Comment: Glad that I'm not the only one, but they already replied my tickets and place a call to my workplace for clearing things up.

I just wish a good luck for you. Cheers.